# Include folder with files into Installer Project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have a software product in WPF/C#, which includes sample sound files to be selected by the user during runtime.

I want the user to click "select should file", and this would automatically open a specific folder, `C:\myCompany\myProduct\sounds`. Then the user chooses the preferred sound.

Additionally, if the user has its own sounds, she can add these to the same folder. Or even can she choose from whatever folder she has audio files (but always the default one will be open in the dialog).

QUESTION IS:

Supposing I have included this folder in the C# project, how should I include this folder and all its content in the Installer project, so that upon installation, the appropriate `C:\myCompany\myProduct\sounds` folder with all the files is created in client machine?

As a final remark, I *don't* want to include these audio files as embedded resources or anything, just plain old copy the very files to a specific destination folder.

Comment: Please mark this as duplicate. The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4522487/401828

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Setup Project with all files from a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748429/visual-studio-setup-project-with-all-files-from-a-folder)